# ignore transparent image part with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following problem:
I made an avatar which is placed over a tile, and I want to ignore the transparent part of the avatar, so I can activate the tile when my mouse hovers over the avatar.

Does someone have an idea how to do this? I was considering using Canvas maybe, but I don't know how.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried so far?  You could probably look for a hover event on both the image and the tile together.

Comment: Hi,

I made this to so far :
http://prntscr.com/1mudm6

ANd as you can see, the transperant part have to be ignored to trigger the tile.